# Aggregate $lookup Array of Objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have collection `schools` with field `groups` and I am attempting to `$lookup` documents from the `users` collection. I am getting empty results however and an extra `schools` document.

**Schools Schema**

```
const SchoolSchema = new Schema({

  groups: [
    {
      name: { type: String },
      color: { type: String },
      userDrivenName: { type: String },
    },
  ]
});

module.exports = School = mongoose.model("School", SchoolSchema);
```

**User Schema**

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  groups: [
    {
      groupId: { type: String },
      name: { type: String },
      color: { type: String },
      userDrivenName: { type: String },
    },
  ]
});
```

**Query**

```
db.schools.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: ObjectId("5d836e584a24e20e6090fd7b")
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      groups: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$groups"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      let: {
        groupId: "$groups._id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            "groups.groupId": "$$groupId"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "groups",

    },

  },

])
```

Results:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5d836e584a24e20e6090fd7b",
        "groups": []
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d836e584a24e20e6090fd7b",
        "groups": []
    }
]
```

Expected Results:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"5d836e584a24e20e6090fd7b",
      "groups":[
         {
            "_id":"5ec01fdc1dfb0a4f08316dfe",
            "name":"GROUP 1",
            "users":[
               {
                  "name":"Luke Skywalker"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3HmzqB8DCQ9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

There's a type mismatch between `groupId` and `groups.groupId` so you need to use [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) (based on your Mongo Playground example),

[$lookup with custom pipelines](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) allows only expression when you use $match so you need [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html) and [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html):

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        let: { groupId: { $toString: "$groups._id" } },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $match: { 
                    $expr: {
                        $in: ["$$groupId","$groups.groupId"]
                    } 
                }
            }
        ],
        as: "groups"
    }
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lPR0-dhR4Ok)